# After so many chars in a string, find the nearest space and put it on a new line

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make everything look tidy in a file but I'm having a problem.
I am asking for `Details` and if it is more then 27 bytes long then I need to find the nearest previous space and put it on a new line.

(using python 3.2)

I am starting with this:

```
Details = input ("Details: ")
delen = len(Details)
if delen >27:
    #Code Here
else:
    pass
```

Is this possible? If so could you give me a hand please?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[str.rfind](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.rfind) is your friend.

```
Details = input ("Details: ")
if len(Details) > 27:
    nearest_space = Details.rfind(' ', 0, 27)
    first, second = Details[:nearest_space], Details[nearest_space:]
else:
    first, second = Details, None
```

Note that `rfind` will raise an exception if no space is found in `Details`.

Comment: That seems to work really well thank you. Only problem is is that the details string can some times be up to 100 chars long so will need to be split in to more then the two. is there anyway to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Python expert.  There are probably some fancy ways of doing this.  I would keep it simple and do:

```
Detail = input ("Details: ")
line_length = 27
delen = len(Detail)
pos = 0
while pos < delen:
    print Detail[pos:pos+line_length]
    pos += line_length
```